# Selectable and draggable at the same time (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

**UPDATE** detailed description what I want to achieve.

I want FullCalendar users to be able to specify their date availability in a calendar for whole month. I want to limit them what type of event they are able to create. Event type = event name. There are 4 types currently

1. available for morning shift (dopoledne in jsfiddle)
2. available for afternoon shift (odpoledne)
3. might do morning shift (můžu dopoledne)
4. might do afternoon shift (můžu odpoledne)

There is a limit of one morning per day and so on. I wanted to make the creation of filling such calendar for users easier so then can fill more than one day at a time. So I thought I would use selectable+draggable. If not maybe I can use selectable and then let user choose which type of event they want to create.  So basically I am looking for simple way to let user create recurring pre-defined events.

For example... the user wants to "create" events for 1-10.4. and then 15-28.4. and then 30.4. In such scenario it would be too much clicking using only draggable.

original post follows

Can I set up FullCallendar a way where the user can drop draggable into more dates? So the same event would be created for more than one day. I was thinking of using selectable but it does not work. Here is my working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/7knL3mtb/55/). Another way how to solve this might be to have pop asking for how many more days the dropped event shall be duplicated. I do not know how to do this either.

```
  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
    //  left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
  //    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
    drop: function(e) {
```

Could someone suggest a solution?

I am using the latest version of FullCalendar.

Comment: selectable is for creating new events, nothing to do with dropping. So no that definitely wouldn't work. I'll think if there's another solution. What version of fullCalendar are you using?

Comment: Btw to be clear you're asking how to create a recurrence pattern, rather than the user be able to drop the same event into different arbitrary locations, is that right?

Comment: I want users to be able to specify their date availability calendar for whole month. So I thought I would use draggable. Maybe I can use selectable and then let user choose which type of event they want to create. I want to limit them what type of event they are able to create. Event type = event name. So basically I am looking for simple way to let user create recurring pre-defined events. I am using the latest version of FC.

Comment: Is the user allowed to specify the recurrence pattern, or is it fixed based on the event type? Can they specify how long it recurs for, or is it always every day for a month (for example)? It's a but unclear how much freedom the user has. It might be better if you update the question with a more complete specification. What you've provided so far is a little bit ambiguous I think.

Comment: updated question. Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes that's quite a bit clearer, thankyou. My first thought is to handle [eventReceive](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive) and pop up a little modal to ask the user if they want to make the event repeat and by how many days (how you make the UI to be the quickest / most user-friendly is up to you I guess). From that you can make it build a recurrence rule, which you can use to then update the newly added event and make it a recurring one.